# White screen on Laptop, Purple Screen on another monitor after install Ubuntu 18.04.02

Tags: boot, nvidia, acer, white-screen

I have a laptop Acer Aspire 4741G with spec: 
Core i3 350M 2.26 Ghz Processor
2 GB DDR3
Nvidia 310M Graphics Card

I installed Ubuntu desktop 18.04.02 bionic beaver from a USB stick successfully but after about 30 minute my screen starts to turn white completely. so i turn it off forcefully and after turn it on it's all white from the starts (even no Acer logo).

i tried to connect it to another monitor, it's not show white screen but still no acer logo to enter BIOS and directly show Ubuntu booting logo. after booting in my other monitor just show purple screen, the cursor still work but i can't do anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but if this always happen after 30 may be related to power settings. Go to Settings > Power and disable everything. Also when this happen you can press Ctrl+Alt+F3 to switch to a terminal (tty3). Login and run `journalctl -k  -p err` last lines may have useful info.

Comment: Consider using a different Ubuntu flavour because 2GB of RAM is really small when running gnome.

Comment: thanks,, apparantely my LCD is broken,, and yes i will consider to use Mint or Xubuntu